# Patterns in Jflex

Tags: java, jflex

My question is **Can i use the patterns in the java code ??** I mean if i have this code can i use **pdf** word in java code i'm looking to use the pattern itself and manipulate it by java so is there any way to do so ?

```
    pdf = "."("full.pdf" | "full.pdf+html" | "pdf")

    <YYINITIAL>
    {
        {pdf}
       {
          String x=pdf; 
          return YYEOF;
       }
    }
```

I had tried searched but the resources is little, thanks for help.

Comment: What do you mean by "the patterns"? The posted code does not look like java after all

Comment: pdf is pattern ->`pdf = "."("full.pdf" | "full.pdf+html" | "pdf")` and the java code is -> `String x=pdf;` it's just smal example

Answer (score 2):

JFlex is not designed as a stand-alone pattern matcher.  So, using that way is unlikely to work ... without significant modification to JFlex.

But the good news is that Java `Pattern` regexes are more expressive than JFlex regexes.

---

On the other hand, if you are asking how to extract the text that has been matched by a lexer regex ... so that you can use it in the Java code inside the `{ ... }` in your parser, then just call `yytext()`; e.g. somewthinfg like this:

```
pdf = "."("full.pdf" | "full.pdf+html" | "pdf")

<YYINITIAL>
{
   {pdf}
   {
      String x=yytext(); 
      return YYEOF;
   }
}
```

See http://jflex.de/manual.html#ScannerMethods

Comment: thanks a lot Stephen i didn't mean that, my example should be like this :

  `{x} {pdf}
   {
      String x=yytext(); 
      return YYEOF;
   }`
then i need to extract the value of pdf.